# SQL - How to replace While loop with any other loop - Performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please suggest me why the below query takes more time to run and How do I improve the performance on the same.
Here I am trying loop a temp table (`#tempPolicyData`) which has data and then using this temp table I am trying to insert into another final temp table only if the `IF BLOCK` condition returns any data. So My final result is 2nd Temp table `#tempImpactedPolicyData`.
Please suggest me how to improve below query in better way, Currently its talking almost 2  minutes

Sample Data For `#tempPolicyData`:

[image]

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Top 1 1 FROM #tempPolicyData)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(50)
       DECLARE @CreatedDate NVARCHAR(10)
       SELECT TOP 1 @AccountNumber =AccountNumber,@CreatedDate=CreateTimestamp FROM #tempPolicyData 

       IF Exists( Select Top 1 1 FROM [dbo].[CheckRecords] where DetailRecord like '%' + @AccountNumber + '%')
         BEGIN
             SELECT PolicyNumber,AccountNumber,Amount
             INTO  #tempImpactedPolicyData 
              FROM #tempPolicyData where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber

        END

       Delete FROM #tempPolicyData where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
    END

    Select * from #tempImpactedPolicyData
```

Comment: Getting rid of the loop completely, or at least turning it into batches, will be a significant improvement. SQL is a set based language, thus it excels at set based processes but performs poorly at iterative ones. Sample data and Expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: If you want an improved version, provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Also, why have you tagged [tag:c#] here? Are you looking to migrate the solution you have from T-SQL to C#? I would suggest not doing so; I see no reason to use C# unless you very specifically need to. If you do, explain why you need to use C# rather than T-SQL.

Comment: are you sure this is this query is working ? This `SELECT * INTO #tempImpactedPolicyData` will result in error the second time it executes

Comment: Provide the table structures and what query you are trying to construct.

Comment: yes that's corrected, I have edited my query and also added sample data, Kindly suggest me

Comment: You haven't added the `CREATE TABLE` command. The query still contains just a loop, which is the slowest way to query. No sample data, no expected results either. One can only guess. It looks like you want to insert rows from `#tempPolicyData` into `#tempImpactedPolicyData` only if there's no matching row in `CheckRecords`. INSERT works with SELECT already. To select rows that have no match use `SELECT` with a LEFT JOIN where the right table has no match, ie it returns NULL

Comment: How to replace a slow thing with any other slow thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this whole operation in **a single query**, by utilizing `DELETE` with an `OUTPUT` clause

```sql
DELETE FROM #tempPolicyData tpd
OUTPUT PolicyNumber, AccountNumber, Amount
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[CheckRecords] cr
    WHERE cr.DetailRecord LIKE '%' + tpd.AccountNumber + '%')
```

If you didn't actually want to delete, just change it to a `SELECT`

```sql
SELECT PolicyNumber, AccountNumber, Amount
FROM #tempPolicyData tpd
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[CheckRecords] cr
    WHERE cr.DetailRecord LIKE '%' + tpd.AccountNumber + '%')
```

Comment: Hi Charlieface, Thanks for the response, I am still seeing almost 1 min time to execute the above query, is their anyway I can still reduce the performance

Comment: Wildcard prefix search`LIKE '%' + something` is always going to be slow because you can't use indexes. Try to find a way to match with an equality `=` on some column, then index that column